# Azure App Service is not returning data from connected Azure SQL Database, shows message "An error has occurred"

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I created a Web Application in .NET framework on Visual Studio 2019 and published it on Azure Web App. The web application is connected to Azure SQL Database and it's job is to return some data when parameters passed through API.

Locally web app runs fine and gives desired output. When API is tested but after deployment on Azure portal, the generated URL- concatenated with required API fields, does not returns the output instead displays a message "An error has occurred".

I tested the API on Postman, it's 500 Internal Server error and displays the same error message. Somehow I am unable to understand what went wrong. Any guesses what could've been done wrong or is there something missing in configuration?

P.S. I am new to Azure webapp, and might be missing something in configurations. Hence all suggestions and help are welcome.

Thanks.

Attaching error message for reference. [Display when I run the Azure generated URL with API tail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AJRz.png)

Comment: I would consider enabling Application Insights for that application. This is a combination of enabling the feature at the portal, and adding Application Insights packages to your app. Once enabled (Application Insights) and deployed (Application wired up with Application Insights client), you can submit requests to it. Once you start experiencing failures, a few minutes later they will appear in Application Insights.

Comment: Is this error message coming from some catch all error bucket within your code? If yes, you may need to change the code a bit to log the original error code and message. Using that you should be able to debug.

Comment: Hello @AnupamChand, thank you for the response. But no, I haven't set anything like this error message. My guess is, it is related to database connection, like some configuration or connection string, etc. and hence, the data that's not being displayed. Instead, this error message pops up. But unable to figure out what is missing or is configured in a wrong manner.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include some code which will make it possible for others recreate the problem? Without that, it is difficult to understand if this is a setup issue or a code issue.